# Select2 multiple - how to set blank default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have a dynamic multiple choice input which uses `Select2`. I need to create a "blank" option which has empty value with some title so it behaves like nothing is selected but user sees that there is selected "All" option. It's because it's counter intuitive when there is nothing selected and users think that it's mandatory.

I think that this could work:

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

But I can't figure out how to make this option selected. The Ajax deletes all options everytime it requests option list from server.

So everytime when there is nothing selected, the "fake" option with title "All" becames selected and if one or more options are selected, the fake option automatically unselects itself.

Comment: Why dont you just put a placeholder instead ? Can you share the code you use to populate your Select2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add selected. When something else are selected, you remove selected and add disabled.

```
<select>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
<option value="value">Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

- clear the selected options when `.select2.fix` has initialized

```js
$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Choose option",
    tags: true, 
    width: "100%",
    allowClear: true, 
    multiple: true
});

// Add this: clear all options when select2 has initialized
if ($('.select2.fix').hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
    $('.select2.fix').val(null).trigger('change');
}
```

```html
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4/dist/css/select2.min.css">
    
<label>The issue</label>
<select name="some_tags[]" class="form-control select2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>     

<label>The solution</label> 
<select name="some_tags[]" class="form-control select2 fix">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

[image]